# file-delete word("links" sim ".txt")

Tags: netlogo

I try to use `file-delete word("links" sim ".txt")` as I use `file-open word("links" sim ".txt")`, but an expected parenthesis is asked after `sim`. Do you know why? How can I manage that?

Comment: Hi @Cédric, could you please provide the code you already tried? You can also follow the guide to maximize your chances to get a quick answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than two strings to combine then you need to use the format (word value1 ...) with the parenthesis BEFORE `word`. See the NetLogo Dictionary for more details. Here is an example that constructs the string you want:

```
to teststrings
  let sim 1
  let str1 (word "links" sim ".txt")
  print str1
  let str2 word "link" sim
  print str2
end
```

I don't understand why your `file-open` works, are you sure that is the format you are using? The code should generate the same error.